# Hadoop+Spark - once application will start properly once will display the error

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, connection, hadoop-yarn, distributed-computing

I have a file with 40 000 lines, in every line single word, each other.

I start Hadoop, master, slaves - everything works:

```
start-dfs.sh;start-yarn.sh;/opt/spark/sbin/start-master.sh;/opt/spark/sbin/start-slaves.sh
```

I run the sample application, which counts the words:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.JavaWordCount --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 2g /opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.0.0.jar hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/input/outputData.fcs
```

and I have problem: once application will start properly and displays the result and once will display the error (and I don't change nothing between the restarts):

```
ERROR shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher: Exception while beginning fetch of 1 outstanding blocks 
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to iws2/172.29.77.40:43688
```

[Link to full log with error](http://wklej.org/id/2785759/)

I have no idea what is wrong. Below my configuration file:

[yarn-site.xml](http://wklej.org/id/2785768/)

All slaves and master are set correctry in files "master", "slaves".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reply.

Files from /opt/hadoop/hadoop/etc/hadoop/ (they are identical on master and slaves):

[core-site.xml](http://wklej.org/id/2787041/)

[hdfs-site.xml](http://wklej.org/id/2787043/)

[mapred-site.xml](http://wklej.org/id/2787044/)

One file that I have modified in Spark (/opt/spark/conf/; it's identical on master and slaves):

[spark-env.sh](http://wklej.org/id/2787045/)

And hosts file:

[/etc/hosts](http://wklej.org/id/2787049/)

Files "master" and "slaves" are identical on all nodes:
[slaves](http://wklej.org/id/2787051/),
[master](http://wklej.org/id/2787052/).

I don't know where is problem.

**EDIT:**

I changed in capacity-scheduler.xml:

```
  <property>
     <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent</name>
     <value>1</value>
  </property>
```

and in yarn-site.xml:

```
  <property>
     <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
     <value>2.1</value>
  </property>
```

Now it works!

**Second option:** I changed input file.

Maybe it will be useful to others.

Comment: You are welcome. However, the answer section is not for questions. Glad it worked. Do you want me to update my answer with the solution (so you can accept it), or you wish to do something else?

Answer (score 1):

The error states:

> Failed to connect to iws2/172.29.77.40:43688

As a result is a network issue. Make sure your cluster is configured correctly and start looking information about this.

Hope this helps.